# Spartacus - Refresh cart details on address change

Tags: angular, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

In my Hybris B2B setup, I have users who can have different carts based on their address. So basically, same user will have 2 seperate carts for 2 seperate address.
I have an independent cmscomponent from where I change the address on a click event and on doing so I want to change the displayed cart as well. Does spartacus provide any service to do it.

I have tried using `this.activeCartService.reloadActiveCart()` but it loads the incorrect cart.

The only way I can get the correct cart on change of address is my doing a page reload, i.e `window.location.reload()`. Is there a way of doing this without a page reload?

Comment: please share some code snippet from where you are trying to reload cart, you should have custom method to by passing address to load cart.

Comment: Hi Raushan, I think I can reload the cart using this.multiCartService.reloadCart(this.cartId, { active: true }); but I am not able to find a method/service 
which will give me the changed/new cartId. Is there a service available which will give me all cartId's of the user based on the shipping address.
So I can use filter to get the cardId associated with the corresponding shipping address. I tried this.savedCartService.getSavedCartList() but its giving me empty data.